# Are updater and updarer default accounts on win 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I inherited a win 2012 server and the security log is full of events **4648** from user **updater**.

I found there is also a **updarer** user and they own lots of running processes.

Their description is: **Microsoft windows Update service**, so they seem to be default users, but I cannot find any information about them. The destination servers reported in event **4648** have exotic names which cannot resolved by dns. Is it correct ? I would like to understand what is happening because the security log is filled very fast by these events and I would like to avoid it.

Update

Here is one of the 4648 events, unfortunately it is not in English language:

```
È stato tentato un accesso utilizzando credenziali esplicite.

Soggetto:
ID sicurezza:       UTENTE-E4COHOO4\updater
Nome account:       updater
Dominio account:        UTENTE-E4COHOO4
ID accesso:     0xF2ECCFC
GUID accesso:       {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Account di cui sono state utilizzate le credenziali:
Nome account:       Administrator
Dominio account:        UTENTE-E4COHOO4
GUID accesso:       {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Server di destinazione:
Nome server di destinazione:    RC-REMOTE.rc.local
Informazioni aggiuntive:    RC-REMOTE.rc.local

Informazioni sul processo:
ID processo:        0x13c8
Nome processo:      C:\Windows\victoria\svchost.exe

Informazioni di rete:
Indirizzo di rete:  -
Porta:          -
```

I found a mysterious **"C:\windows\victoria"** folder and according to [this discussion](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/507686-virus-removal-help-2008r2-and-now-2012-ric_minderd) (search for victoria) it is some sort of malware.

Do you confirm **updater** and **updarer** are not default accounts on Win 2012 ?

Comment: Try posting examples from your logs. From what you have written so far it sounds like you have a compromised server, but I cannot be sure without seeing logs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely have some sort of virus/malware on your server. Scan your entire network for viruses and possibly reinstall the server or restore it from a known good backup.